# Create a series of increasingly larger files

Tags: bash

I need to test an sftp host for its cutoff of file size upload limitation. I wanted to make a series of files that were of increasingly larger sizes, to try to upload them all and see where they failed.

I was doing `for i in {10000..100000} ; do dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile$i bs=$i count=1  ; done ;`
but that was taking too long, and the files I was getting were starting at 10K, going to 11K, 12K, etc. I want the size to jump in larger increments.

How can a make a series of files that won't have such a fine-grained size difference? I'm thinking the limit is between 0 and 1 MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `dd(1)`:

> bs=BYTES
>
> /.../
>
> BLOCKS and BYTES may be followed by the following multiplicative
>   suffixes: c =1, w =2, b =512, kB =1000, K =1024, MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024

Alternatively, if you have a recent version of bash, the `{}` construct also takes a step parameter:

```
for i in {10000..100000..1000}; do dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile$i bs=$i count=1 ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

For academic purposes, this would give a command 1k input files in increments of 1024 bytes by appending to the same file.

```
while ((++n<=1024)); do
    printf '\0%.s' {1..1024} >&3
    xxd -g 1 /dev/stdin; echo # sftp command here
done <<<'' 3>/dev/stdin
```

But... trial and error? I'd find a better way.

Comment: If you're sure there's a better way I'm all ears :D

Comment: Have you checked, and it's actually the sftp server that's doing the enforcing? Why would there be a per-file limit? If there were such a thing it would probably be a filesystem or some other limit, in which case, ssh in and find how to query it.